# Use Bootstrap navbar without capitals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using quite a few Bootstrap navbars and all the text appears all in capitals by default. How can I override this default styling?

Comment: Which version of bootstrap is this on?

Comment: Very old but I'm having this issue too. I'm running version 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this style for your nav list in your own stylesheet example:

```
.Nav {text-transform: capitalize;}
```

You might need to add `!important` before the semi colon.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of automatic capitalizing the first letters in the Bootstrap links I use `text-transform: initial` instead of `text-transform: capitalize;`:

```
<style>
  .initial a {
    text-transform: initial;
  }
</style>

<nav class='navbar navbar-expand-sm initial'>
  <ul class='navbar-nav'>
    <li class='nav-item'>
      <a class='nav-link' href='#'>Link name</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```